# How to set available space starting from right side of the screen eg. available_space = screen_width - x

Tags: python

```
def _create_fleet(self):
    """Create the fleet of aliens."""
    alien = Alien(self)
    alien_height, alien_width = alien.rect.size

    #margin
    available_space_y = self.settings.screen_height - alien_height
    #spacing
    number_aliens_y = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)

    #margin
    available_space_x = (self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width))
    #spacing
    number_columns = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

    for column in range(number_columns):
        for alien_number in range(number_aliens_y):
            self._create_alien(alien_number, column)
```

available_space_x = (self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)) takes two widths from the right screen, I was wondering if it was possible to take it off from the left side instead.

Comment: `available_space_x = 2 * alien_width`?

Comment: Should have added this, I'd like the first alien to be placed at the top right corner with a top and bottom margin of 1 alien_width. Then add more rows and columns from right to left.